# Printing objects which are in Arraylist - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10

Tags: java, collections

I have created a Teacher class and instantiated 10 teacher objects and added them to an Arraylist.

Now when I try to print the content of those object in a loop, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.school.Main.main(Main.java:141)



ArrayList<Teacher> aTeacherArrayList = new ArrayList<Teacher>();

for ( x = 1; x<=10; x++) {

    Teacher aTeacher = new Teacher();

    aTeacher.setTeacherSalary(60000);

    aTeacher.setTeacherAddress("189 Orr Road" + x );

    aTeacher.setTeacherFirstName("Tony" + x);

    aTeacher.setTeacherLastName("Fong" + x);

    aTeacherArrayList.add(aTeacher);

  }

  for(i=0;i<=aTeacherArrayList.size();i++){

        System.out.println("in the looop");
         System.out.println(aTeacherArrayList.get(i).getTeacherFirstName() + " " + 
         aTeacherArrayList.get(i).getTeacherLastName());

   }
```

Comment: Modify your for:  for (int i=0;i<10;i++) { // do whathever} or even better for ( Teacher t : aTeacherArrayList).

Comment: Index starts with 0 to length-1. index of first object will be 0 and last object will be 9. your for loop will index through objects from 1 to 10. 10 is out of bound

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to this

```
for(i=0; i<aTeacherArrayList.size(); i++){
```

If your array length is 'm' , the elements start from 0 to 'm-1'

Comment: Thank YOu. Learning basic in Java

Comment: @SidharthBasam you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick sign beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` (and arrays in general) indexes are numbered 0 to `array.size() - 1`.  This part `for(i=0; i<=aTeacherArrayList.size(); i++)` should be `for(int i = 0;  i < aTeacherArrayList.size(); i++)`.